# calling non global namespace function from script tags inside html files

Tags: javascript, html, namespaces, global

I have a JavaScript file with the following:

```
(function(){
ApiCall = {};
ApiCall.serviceRoot = "http://Serviceurl/";

ApiCall.GetProducts = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ApiCall.serviceRoot + "GetProducts",
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        error:function(statusCode){
            return statusCode;
        }
    });
};})();
```

I have a scipt tag in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert(ApiCall.GetProducts());</script>
```

I am getting, ApiCall is not defined exception which makes sense because of the ApiCall not being in the global namespace but its accessible from another normal .js file so how would I access this from a script tag?

Or do i add a function inside another javascript file that is in the global namespace to call the ApiCall? Surely that would be unnecessary run around?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: either look at the revealing module pattern, or set it to a global inside the function, i.e. `window.ApiCall = {};`

Comment: I will try that and get back to you thank you!

Comment: actually, you already had a global (ApiCall) and didn't know it... you are more likely simply running the 2nd code before the 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you dandavis,

It turns out there was something preventing my Api.js file from completing (Syntax error maybe) so when I called it, ApiCall was undefined.

Thank you for your help!

atmd, the revealing module pattern is great and I will use this in future so thank you!

Thanks,
Warren